# How to Rehab a Bicep Tear

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, injury

I'm writing this on behalf of my gym instructor who unfortunately doesn't have Internet access.

Last fortnight he suffered a slight tear in his left bicep while moving some heavy equipment. He has now somewhat recovered and is wondering what kind of exercise/warm-up/weight-lifting will help re-build the muscles.

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, has he seen a doctor?  According to [LiveStrong's article on healing a torn biceps muscle](http://www.livestrong.com/article/21577-healing-torn-bicep-muscle/):

1. Get a doctor to diagnose how bad it is
2. Evaluate if surgery is necessary (it is for major tears)
3. Ice your arm
4. Consult your doctor for proper physical therapy exercises
5. Eliminate any activity that causes the biceps pain

The [Sports Science Orthopedics Clinic's article](http://www.ssoc.co.za/biceps-rupture.html) echoes many of the same sentiments.  This isn't a self-diagnosis and repair type of issue.  The SSOC article does list some stretches that can help--but the physical therapy really needs to be overseen by someone with the correct background.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I tore my bicep doing barbell shoulder shrugs in late december I had to have surgery to reattach it. It can get worse if not properly treated. Deffinately go see a doctor. I had surgery and just finished with a couple months of rehab. It is slow progress getting strength back but start with simple range of motion and stretching exercises then move onto light weights. It can take 6-9 months to get full strength back.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what exercises you did to rehab? Because I think the OP already realizes he has to do some exercises